# What if the seas had traces of copper and iron?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

I'm aware that acid rainwater and Copper makes green (but the sea isn't acid), while Iron promotes the growth of plankton.
But what if traces of the metals were in the sea.

how would it affect our world for example?

Comment: "How would it affect our world" is almost certainly too broad. Can you narrow this down to some specific aspect of our world? (Also, as Frostfyre points out, this is already pretty much the way it is, but we could read your question as simply "what if there was much more of it?".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phytoplankton really, really like iron - adding it causes [plankton blooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_fertilization). The oceans would be much more productive if they had more iron.

More phytoplankton (plants) = more zooplankton = more fish and squid = more things that eat fish and squid.

And molluscs use copper as their respiratory pigment (to carry oxygen in their blood), so perhaps there would be more squid and fewer fish?

Copper is also toxic in higher quantities, so you wouldn't want to have too much in your oceans!

Answer (score 7):

There are already trace amounts of almost all known elements in the Earth's oceans. According to [this article](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/Martin/martin_3.php) by NASA, John Martin focused a good portion of his life on determining the exact concentration of metals in the ocean. Between Martin and Moss Landing: "[t]hey found nearly an entire periodic table in the oceans."

So, what effect would it have? See Earth.

Comment: +1 This was exactly what I was going to say, although if there were large amounts of potassium permanganate you'd have a lovely purple colour... oh and no marine life :D